# Creating a JSON - Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, angular5

I have a JSON read to UI and modifiled as part of review process. Finally I want to save New data to a New folder/File.
 Code Sample below - Always ends with **POST call in error** :

```
SaveFinalData(){

 this.postJson<Reaction> 
 ('./assets/ICP/Reviewed/Json/out.json',
    this.reactionDatabase.reactiondataChange.value);
 }

postJson<Reaction>(url: string, Reaction: any){

//let body = JSON.stringify({ Reaction });   

this.http.post(url, body)
.subscribe(
    (val) => {
        console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
    },
    response => {
      console.log("POST call in error", response);
    },
    () => {
        console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
    });
```

}

Have tried below 2 alternatives:

(1)

```
var theJSONdata = JSON.stringify({ Reaction }); 
   window.localStorage.setItem('./assets/ICP/Reviewed/Json/out.json', theJSONdata)
```

**Result -- NO LUCK!**

(2)

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile') 
var file = './assets/ICP/Reviewed/Json/out.json'
var obj = {name: 'JP'} //SAMPLE DATA

jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, function (err) {
console.error(err)
```

})

**Result -- NO LUCK!** --> GIVES ERROR **fs.writeFile is not a function**

Pls kindly help/guide me to reach the final result....Thanks

Comment: Do you intend to download the file from the server or from the front end?

Comment: nope....I am trying to write an output file into a specific path on server...

Comment: Are you using Angular to write a file at the server?

Comment: using angular 5

Comment: Sorry, you need to use some back end technology such as Node.js to write a file on the server. Angular is a front end technology not suitable for the requirement you have.